# Avocado plant wilting

Tags: transplanting, avocado, wilt

[image]

I recently transplanted my avocado plant from a cup of water to a pot of soil (ph6.5-7) as the tips of the leaves started going brown. 
Since being transplanted the leaves have now drooped and are drying/curling at the ends (picture is of the worst one, which also has small light coloured spots the rest do not).
I've checked the water level with a meter and it says it is sitting at moist which is the middle of the meter. 
It has not been sitting in direct sunlight and todays weather has been around 12 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Looks like the roots are rotting.

Answer (score 2):

Avocado does not like to have its roots disturbed at all. When moving from water to soil if you broke or twisted or bent any of the larger roots this will cause it to have a major headache. The best you can do right now is leave it be, moist but not wet in well drained soil and if it recovers introduce it to more and more light. Avocado does best in full sun but clearly needs to be introduced slowly after the shock of transplanting. For future experimenting now that you have seen roots in water and benefited from the educational experience, next time better to germinate from the start in soil. Then you can transplant to a larger pot with the root ball intact with minimal damage to roots.

12 deg C is pretty cool for an avocado. They are happier at 20-30 but will protestingly survive cooler, so do not expect a lot in cold temperatures.